# Combining object positioning and labeling in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3js and (probably foolishly) am exploring its value as a simple navigation tool. I [have managed to cobble together a basic page that works](http://d3.geotheory.co.uk/linking.html), but it seems rather verbose and I'm wondering if anyone has any pointers how it might be reworked to be more elegant and possibly integrate the label and circle plotting functions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <div id="status" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;
        color:white;background-color:grey;font-size:small"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // functions for adding a 'status' box with link info
    function addStatus(targetURL){document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=targetURL;}
    function clearStatus(){document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=null;}

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 200);

    var dataset =  [[100, 100, "http://google.com/", "Google"],
                    [300, 100, "http://yahoo.com/", "Yahoo"]];

    // Add labels
    sampleSVG.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d[0]})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d[1]})
        .text(function(d) {return d[3];});

    // Add circles and functionality
    sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("fill", "transparent")
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .style("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("r", 50)
        .attr("cx", function(d){return d[0]})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return d[1]})
         .on("mouseover", 
             function(d){ d3.select(this).style("stroke", "black");
             addStatus(d[2]); }
             )
         .on("mouseout", 
             function(){
                 d3.select(this).style("stroke", "grey");
                 clearStatus(); } )
        .on("mouseup", function(d){window.location = d[2];});


    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two calls to select circles and text if there's one label per circle. That is, add the circles and labels on the same selection.

```
var sel = sampleSVG.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter();
sel.append("text")
   ...
sel.append("circle")
   ...
```

You could even do everything in a single call chain.

```
sampleSVG.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    ...
    .append("text");
```

This will append the `text` elements to the `circle` elements though and may not produce the result you want in all cases (in particular with respect to event handlers).

Beyond that, d3 doesn't provide any functionality out of the box to place both shapes and labels at the same time. There are libraries such as [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/) that provide functionality for that though.

It might be easiest to write your own wrapper function that, given the data, appends both shapes and labels in the way you want.

Comment: Hot off the bl.ocks! Thanks chaps.